# Is there a sorted/detailed Tkinter tk command options library?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
```

Where can I find the options like `root.configure()` or any other widgets method and option with detailed explanation / example? The manual from many website is incomplete or unsorted.

I tried to use idle with command like help (`Tk.config`) but the explanation is too simple.

Should I use other framework beside tkinter?

Comment: I recommend removing the last question, as it's completely unrelated to the first part of the question. Also, answers to the last question will be highly subjective and opinionated, which will likely cause this question to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following reference materials for Tkinter.

[Effbot Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

[Tkinter 8.5 Reference Manual](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

[PDF of Tkinter 8.5 Reference Manual](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf)

Comment: thanks for suggestion but any source better than this ?
its difficult to find some option for example like root.title("") root.maxsize("") etc

Comment: Those two are the best I know. Tkinter 8.5 Reference Manual is pretty extensive... The PDF link on that site give you the whole thing in an easily searchable format.